# Тег dl показывается в разных браузерах по разному почему?

Tags: html, css

```css
.horizontal_dl {
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.horizontal_dl dd {
    margin-left: 155px;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 19px;
}
.horizontal_dl dt {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  
}
dl, dt {
  color: #000;
  font-size: .9em;
}
dl {
  margin-top: 0;
}
dt {
  font-weight: 700;
}
dd {
  margin: 0 0 .563em;
}
.text_upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
 <dl class="horizontal_dl">
   <dt class="text_upper">Full Name</dt>
   <dd>Robert Smith</dd>
   <dt class="text_upper">D.o.b.</dt>
   <dd>05 June 1988</dd>
</dl>
```

Почему тег `<dl>` который входит в тройку элементов `<dl>, <dt>, <dd>,` предназначенных для создания списка определений показывается в разных браузерах по разному и как это исправить?

> Пример:Если вы смотрите данный код с `Сhrome` то все нормально будет у
>   вас показыватся но если вы посмотрите с `Mozilla` (developer edition
>   данный момент у меня стоит) то увидите фантастические отступы которые
>   откуда то взялись .

Вот [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x1vbmtmb/2/) смотрите в `mozille` и увидите разницу.

Comment: А зачем на `dd` и `dt` висит `flex`, если потомков у них всё равно нет?

Comment: @andreymal логично .. :(  если удалить получу ненужные отступы.

Comment: Да и вообще зачем здесь flex, на флоатах вроде бы легко верстается https://jsfiddle.net/89caropd/2/

Comment: Но почему с flex разные результаты в лисе и хроме, я и сам не понял

Comment: @andreymal flex лучше float-ов в любых ситуациях.

Comment: @andreymal да проблема глобальная

Comment: float лучше flex в 99% ситуаций. Не следует применять flex там, где он неуместен. Плюс не забываем про плохую его поддержку не слишком свежими браузерами. Или даже свежими, раз у вас такая проблема возникла ;)

Comment: Впрочем, если кто-нибудь напишет рабочий ответ с flex, это тоже будет неплохо

Comment: @andreymal float сломает вашу верстку а flex уместен всегда надо проста знать как правильно его применять .Боги flex-a помогут мне  :)

Comment: float ни разу не ломал мне мою вёрстку за все десять лет его юзания мной, а вот flex ломает не только мою, но и вашу ;) Надо знать, как правильно применять float :D

Comment: @andreymal тогда значит вы не разу за вашу десять лет не использовали float в синергии с position absolute.Не поймите меня не правильно вашь опыт побольше моей в десят раз и даже больше но float меня всегда бесило и слава богу что есть этот flex

Comment: Непонятно о чём вы говорите, о какой «синергии» речь. Но наверно продолжать не стоит, оффтопик всё-таки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что следующий код может помочь вам получить нужные результаты. Я только преобразовал `dd, dl и dt` часть вашего кода и надеюсь это поможет вам.

```css
dl {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
dl dt {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
    color: #000;
  font-size: .9em;
}
dl dd {
  flex:0 0 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

dl {
  margin-top: 0;
}
dt {
  font-weight: 700;
}
dd {
  margin: 0 0 .563em;
}
.text_upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
 <dl class="horizontal_dl">
   <dt class="text_upper">Full Name</dt>
   <dd>Robert Smith</dd>
   <dt class="text_upper">D.o.b.</dt>
   <dd>05 June 1988</dd>
</dl>
```

Все работает как часы поставтье это в вашь **jsfiddle** и протестите